# Instagram API Only Allowing Last 15 Photos

Tags: token, instagram, instagram-api

With the June 1 changes I can access my Instagram with the API but it only lets me access the last 15 or so images now.

e.g. 
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/shortcode/BEuVPPHnmZT?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXX.X

I updated the token with the scope of &scope=public_content+likes+comments+relationships+basic
but I still see in the client all the scopes are NA

What could I be missing? Any ideas? It is a simple app that takes the JSON and turns it into magic.

thanks

Paul

Answer (score 0):

The `NA` that you see under Review Status will only get updated after you've submitted your app for review. Also, in Sandbox Mode, Instagram only returns the  20 most recent images to you.

Answer (score 0):

In Sandbox Mode your app can only "see" the last 20 posts by you, or any of your Sandbox users. This is a short [article explaining the new Instagram API limits](https://medium.com/@emersonthis/instagram-on-websites-the-new-landscape-62c91d733894#.psynexzi3). To unlock this restriction you'll have to "Go Live" through the submission process, but you will most likely get rejected because there is now only a very narrow set of use cases which they will allow.

Answer (score -1):

Great that you've updated the scope, but doesn't look like you have access to it.  You need to submit your app to a permissions review for Instagram to open access to the scopes that you've asked for.

Comment: You are confusing scopes with sandbox mode. I recommend you have a look at [this Instagram API article](https://medium.com/@emersonthis/instagram-on-websites-the-new-landscape-62c91d733894#.psynexzi3) which detangles them.